# Why files are missing while installing deb file?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, debian, deb

I build a deb file for Apache2 from its source, also I was able to install and run successfully in the machine which I used to compile. But when I copy(SCP) that deb file to another machine and installed, log directory (/CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs/var/log/) for apache2 is missing in the newly installed system.in both cases,

Installed using command dpkg -i file_name.deb

Can someone say what will be the reason and how can I solve it?

Compiler:

```
root@compiler:/build/result# cd /CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs/
root@compiler:/CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs# ls
usr  var
```

another machine :

```
root@ubuntu-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1:~# ls /CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs/
usr
root@ubuntu-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1:~#
```

As you can see the "var" directory is missing when installing the same deb file on another machine. I used following config to build deb file

```
./configure --enable-layout=Debian --prefix=/CloudS/Packages/apache2-cs --sysconfdir=/etc/apache2-cs --enable-rewrite=shared --enable-speling=shared --with-pcre --with-include-apr --with-include-aprutils --enable-load-all-modules --with-suexec-caller=cloudS-www --with-suexec-logfile=/var/log/apache2-cs/suexec.log --with-suexec-bin=/usr/lib/apache2-cs/suexec --with-suexec-docroot=/var/www --with-suexec-userdir=public_html --with-suexec-uidmin=100 --enable-suexec=shared --with-program-name=apache2-cs --enable-logio
make clean
make 
checkinstall --install=no --pakdir=/build/result/
```

Comment: Show (the relevant part of) your `debian/rules` file and any pertinent supplemental files like `debian/dirs`. Not using such a wacky destination directory for this would probably simplify things.

Comment: @tripleee I used checkinstall to build deb file, so i did not create any debian/ directory .

Answer (score 0):

`checkinstall` only examines what `make` does, and `make` doesn't create any log files. You can force the addition of a path into the generated package with `checkinstall`'s `--include` option. See further its [manual page.](https://manpages.debian.org/buster-backports/checkinstall/checkinstall.8.en.html)